# Deleting Ubuntu partitions dual boot with windows 10

Tags: grub

After I Deleted Ubuntu partitions dual boot with windows 10 it say grub rescue .Plz help I don't know what to do, I only have two partitions the C for windows and the D for data .

Answer (score 0):

Use a bootable Windows 8/8.1/10 USB drive and select the repair option when the setup dialog shows up...

It'll automatically remove grub and repair booting for you!!!